# Back to top links will not work

Tags: jquery, hyperlink

First post here so hey.

I'm trying to create a back to top link which I have correctly done many times before, but on the site I'm currently working on it just refuses to work! I've been trying to use the animatescroll.js as I have done many times however it just refuses to work! Any help would be appreciated as it's the final piece of the puzzle!

```
<body>
    <div class="site-wrap" id="site-wrap">
      <!-- Intro Section -->
      <div class="main-banner full-width-div">
          <div class="container">
              <div class="row" id="social">
                  <h2><center>Pre-Register Now</center></h2>
                  <div class="col-xs-4"><center><img class="social-buttons" src="img/Twitter_Icon_Black.png"></center></div>
                  <div class="col-xs-4"><center><img class="social-buttons" src="img/Facebook_Icon_Black.png"></center></div>
                  <div class="col-xs-4"><center><img class="social-buttons" src="img/Google-Plus_Icon_Black.png"></center></div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>


<!-- What is Wukus Section -->
        <div class="whatiswukus full-width-div-1"><center>
            <h2>What is Wukus?</h2>
            <p>Wukus is a new era of talent discovery, a revolutionary global platform putting the hottest talents in front of the people that matter. Wukus is designed by the industry for the industry; it’s not what you know, it’s who you know.</p>
            </center>
        <img src="img/vision.png"></div>


<!-- Vision Section -->

        <div class="whatiswukus full-width-div-1"><center>
            <h2>Vision</h2>
            <p>The Wukus vision is to impact people around the world through the power of entertainment, creating legacies and being the driver of positive change. Our philanthropic initiatives provide opportunities, rehabilitation and fun to those who need it most. Giving back is what we do best.</p>
            </center>
        <img src="img/dream.png"></div>


<!-- Dream Section -->

        <div class="whatiswukus full-width-div-1">
            <div id="showdream"><center><h2>Dream <i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i></h2></center></div>
            <div class="dreamcontent" style="display:none;"><center><p>The founders of Wukus understand that turning dreams into reality can be tough. Wukus has been designed with your needs at the forefront of everything we do, supporting you on your journey.</p>
                </center></div>
        <img src="img/connect.png"></div>



<!-- Connect Section -->

        <div class="whatiswukus full-width-div-1">
            <div id="showconnect"><center><h2>Connect <i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i></h2></center></div>
            <div class="connectcontent" style="display:none;"><center><p>Wukus connects the entertainment industry like never before; our concept goes far beyond the technology itself.  Wukus culture believes in the connection of people, driven by talents working towards common goals.</p>
                </center></div>
        <img src="img/discover.png"></div>



<!-- Discover Section -->

        <div class="whatiswukus full-width-div-1">
            <div id="showdiscover"><center><h2>Discover <i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i></h2></center></div>
            <div class="discovercontent" style="display:none;"><center><p>Wukus is more than an app, it’s an experience. Our platform will not only allow industry professionals to find you at the touch of a button, but also gives you the tools to discover more about yourself, and your brand. We take discovery to the next level.</p>
                </center></div></div>



<!-- Not a talent section -->

        <div class="not-a-talent full-width-div-1">
            <div id="shownottalent"><center><h2>Not a talent? <i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i></h2></center></div>
            <div class="nottalentcontent" style="display:none;"><center><p>Not a talent? Not to worry. The founders have also designed features for public users; we wouldn’t want you to miss out on the fun! ...Oh and did we mention Wukus is free.</p>
                </center></div>
        <img src="img/miami.png"></div>



<!-- Pre register Miami Section -->

        <div class="whatiswukus-miami full-width-div-1"><center>
            <h2>Miami</h2>
            <p>Pre-register now to become a founding member and a chance to win a trip to Miami, Wukus style.</p>
            </center></div>



<!-- Footer Section -->
        <div class="footer">
      <center>
          <p>
          <a href="#" onclick="$('body').animatescroll();">Back To Top</a>
          </p>
          <p>
          Copyright © Wukus 2015. All Rights Reserved
          </p>
          <p>
          <a href="privacy.html">Privacy Agreement</a>
          </p>
          <p>
          <a href="mailto:support@whoiswukus.com" target="_top">Contact Us</a>
          </p>
          </center>
      </div>
      </div>

    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#showdream').click(function() {
                $('.dreamcontent').slideToggle("slow");
        });

        $('#showconnect').click(function() {
                $('.connectcontent').slideToggle("slow");
        });

        $('#showdiscover').click(function() {
                $('.discovercontent').slideToggle("slow");
        });

        $('#shownottalent').click(function() {
                $('.nottalentcontent').slideToggle("slow");
        });
    });  
    </script> 
      <script src="js/animatescroll.js"></script>

    </script>
  </body>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is not working?  Is there an error or something strange happening?

Comment: try `$('body,html').animatescroll()` and are you sure you're meant to do it onclick?

Comment: @JasonWilczak you press on the back to top link and nothing happens at all.

Comment: @Pete That doesn't work either. http://plugins.compzets.com/animatescroll/ this is the plugin I'm using and I've just followed the instructions... I have used this plugin in the exact same way before and it worked perfectly.

Comment: @BenYoule, I tried looking at the site but it is blocked by my works firewall settings.  If you press f12 on your browser and have a look at the console tab, do you see any errors?

Answer (score 0):

You no need any external jQuery libraries. Use the simple jQuery code to do this.

```js
/**
 * Show or hide the button depending on the scroll position.
 */
function animateButton() {
    var button = $('#back-to-top');
    var scrollPosition = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (scrollPosition > 400) {
        button.fadeIn();
    } else {
        button.fadeOut();
    }
}
 
/**
 * Create the button and append it to the body.
 */
$(function () {
    $('<a id="back-to-top">Back to Top</a>')
        .click(function () {
            $('html,body').animate({
                scrollTop: 0
            }, 1200);
            return false;
        })
        .appendTo($('body'));
});
 
/**
 * Run the animateButton function on window resize, scroll, and load.
 */
$(window).resize(animateButton);
$(window).scroll(animateButton);
$(window).load(animateButton);
```

The above code is enough for your functionality.